# Using React Boilerplate from (react-boilerplate), how co I add a NavBar to my home page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've written a few rudimentary apps in React, but I'm fairly new to the React Boiler-Plate (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate).  I'm doing a deep dive to create an app where I can simply input a string from one page and get a list of the strings from my DB on a second page... super simple.  There are sooo many moving parts to the boilerplate that is pretty difficult to figure out how to add a working nav component to my main page.

So far I have figured out that the `container` and the `component` folders are where my playground will be.  I have created an simple About page and linked it up through the existing Router to display at `/about`.  Now I want to add a Nav bar to my home page to access that `/about` page.  I am confident I know how to create a component and display it where I would like.  So far my `Nav` component is being rendered within my `HomePage` component like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Nav from '../Nav/index';

export default class HomePage extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> Welcome to the String Motel where string come to stay... forever</h1>
        <Nav/>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

When I add links to my Nav component like this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import {Link, IndexLink} from 'react-router';

export default class Nav extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Nav Component</h2>
        <IndexLink to='/'>Insert String</IndexLink>
        <Link to='/museum'>Museum</Link>
        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error I'm not sure I understand:

```
warning.js:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Nav`.
    in Nav (created by HomePage)
    in div (created by HomePage)
    in HomePage (created by LoadableComponent)
    in LoadableComponent (created by Route)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter
    in IntlProvider (created by LanguageProvider)
    in LanguageProvider (created by Connect(LanguageProvider))
    in Connect(LanguageProvider)
    in Provider
```

The export is fine as it seems to function without the `<Link>` added.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should import Link from 'react-router-dom'. Check if that helps

Comment: I forgot to add that step in my question.  I tried it and it resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so adding my solution here in case anyone else did:

You need to import

`import {Link, IndexLink} from 'react-router-dom'`

instead of from 
`'react-router'`

That fixed everything for me.